# npm doesn't install devDependencies recursively

Tags: node.js, npm

There is `connect-assets` in my `package.json`'s dependencies. And its `package.json` looks like:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "connect-file-cache": "0.2.4",
    "mime": "1.2.2",
    "snockets": "1.3.6",
    "underscore": "1.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "0.1.14",
    "coffee-script": "~1.3.1",
    "connect": "1.8.5",
    "nib": "0.2.0",
    "bootstrap-stylus": "0.2.0",
    "nodeunit": "0.5.4",
    "stylus": "0.22.2",
    "request": "2.1.1",
    "watchit": "0.0.4",
    "less": "1.3.0"
  }
```

But when I ran `npm install`(with or without `--dev` and `--dev-all`), it only installed `connect-assets`, no `stylus`, `nib`, etc.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply because the `npm` should **not** work this way. If I want to install the `devDependencies` of some depended modules, I have to enter their directories.

Answer (score 0):

One should be aware that npm will not deliver files that are specified in the `.npmignore` file. This might be the culprit if one was looking to use files in a devDependency that exist in the git repo, but mysteriously are not present in the npm delivery.